# Get Text after word at specific position

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have file like this

```
TT;12-11-18;text;abc;def;word
AA;12-11-18;tee;abc;def;gih;word
TA;12-11-18;teet abc;def;word
TT;12-11-18;tdd;abc;def;gih;jkl;word
```

I want output like this

```
TT;12-11-18;text;abc;def;word
TA;12-11-18;teet abc;def;word
```

I want to get `word` if it occur at position 5 after date `12-11-18`. I do not want this occurrence if its found after this position that is at 6th or 7th position. Count of position start from date `12-11-18`
I want tried this command

```
cat file.txt|grep "word" -n1
```

This print all occurrence in which this pattern `word` is matched. How should I solve my problem?

Comment: Your question and proposed output are not in line. You state that you would like the have the lines where the word "word" is in a field 5 fields further than the field matching '12-11-18'. Your second line does not match this criterion.

Comment: I only want those lines in which field is after 5th position. I do not want those lines in which it is in sixth or seventh position. If I want to match word at any position I would I simply used `grep "word" file.txt` command

Comment: How do you define the 5th position? Eg. in your expected output you place `TT;12-11-18;text;abc;def;word` where `word` in in field 6 and `12-11-18` in field 2, so that is 4 position. While in the second line, `TA;12-11-18;teet abc;def;word` the difference is 3 position. Or do you mean that `word` should be in field `5`. In that case, you second line is not correct as it is in field 4.

Comment: Every line of your sample input contains `word` and your expected output includes lines where `word` does not appear at position 5. You're making it very difficult to help you come up with the right solution.

Comment: Sorry as my question is confusing to you. I mentioned in question that I want to have `word` after it is appearing at position 5 in date. I am starting the count from data `12-11-18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(GNU awk):

```
awk -F"[; ]" '/12-11-18/ && $6=="word"' file
```

Or `sed` one:

```
sed -n '/12-11-18;\([^; ]*[; ]\)\{3\}word/p' file
```

Or grep with basically the same regex(different escape):

```
grep -E "12-11-18;([^; ]*[; ]){3}word" file
```

`[^; ]` means any character that's not `;` or (space).
`*` means match any repetition of former character/group.
-- `[^; ]*` means any length string that don't contain `;` or space, the `^` in `[^; ]` is to negate.

`[; ]` means `;` or space, either **one** occurance.
`()` is to group those above together.
`{3}` is to match three repetitives of former chracter/group.

As a whole `([^; ]*[; ]){3}` means `;`/space separated three fields included the delimiters.

As @kvantour points out, if there could be multiple spaces at one place they could be faulty.
To consider multiple spaces as **one** separator, then:

```
awk -F"(;| +)" '/12-11-18/ && $6=="word"'
```

and

```
grep -E "12-11-18;([^; ]*(;| +)){3}word"
```

or GNU sed (posix/bsd/osx sed does not support `|`):

```
sed -rn '/12-11-18;([^; ]*(;| +)){3}word/p'
```

Comment: Could you please explain this expression `([^; ]*[; ]){3}`?

Comment: @Sarah Updated in answer.

Comment: This is not a good answer as multiple spaces in a single line might break the command.

Comment: @kvantour  Updated. It's a tricky thing though, max consideration/compatibility trade with accuracy.